# ActionMailer - Gmail Classifies Message As Spam mailgun

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

my configurgation setting is

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "#{ENV['SITE_SCHEME'] || 'http'}://#{ENV['SITE_HOST'] || 'api.staging.engineer.ai'}"
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: (ENV['SITE_HOST'] || 'api.staging.engineer.ai') }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun
config.action_mailer.mailgun_settings = {
  api_key: '<KEY>',
  domain: 'engineer.ai'
}
```

and I have checked the headers and footers. Removing them doesn't change anything.

Comment: Never add credentials to the question!

Comment: This happens most of the time because of the wrong DNS records. Do you have other TXT records than those from Mailgun on the same domain scope?

Comment: @Tobias   <% if lead.product.try(:title) == "Mobile Apps" %>
    <% pro_name = "Mobile" %>
  <% elsif lead.product.try(:title) == "Wearables" %>
      <% pro_name = "Wearable" %>
  <% else %>
      <% pro_name = lead.product.try(:title) %>
  <% end %>
  <% if lead.platforms.count > 1 %>
    <% platform_label = "platforms" %>
  <% else %>
    <% platform_label = "platform" %>
  <% end %>
because of these codes the spam is happening.